# Humankind knows the prime factorization of the first how many consecutive integers?

Tags: prime-numbers, computer-science, factoring, prime-factorization

I am only looking for an approximation.

I'm guessing the answer must be somewhere between $10^{20}$ and $10^{50}$.

.

Edit:
Okay so my first initial estimation was pretty poor...
I should have realized that $10^{50}$ was equal to the number of atoms composing the entire planet... And even $10^{30}$ was equal to the number of atoms composing the Eiffel Tower, still way too much. Pew's comment gives us an upper bound of about $10^{17}$.
And I've just made a small program that calculated the prime factorization of the first $10^7$ integers in an hour. And I'm pretty sure that more experienced programmers with more powerful computers should be able to compute the prime factorization of at least the the first $10^{10}$ integers.
So we have narrowed the possibilities. The answer must be between $10^{10}$ and $10^{17}$.

Comment: What does it mean that humankind knows the prime factorization? Does it mean that somebody, at some time, has determined the factorization, or must it be stored somewhere permanently, or what?

Comment: [There are only about $10^{21}$ bytes of digital information in total](http://www.theguardian.com/media/pda/2010/aug/02/infographic-data-cloud), not even enough to "know" (that is, store) the lower end of your estimate, and I'm sure most of that information isn't integer factorizations...

Comment: Human kind has developed [powerful tools for *rapidly* factoring *huge* numbers](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM). Does this answer your question?

Comment: @pew Don't assume!